# How to unpack a function-returned tuple?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterable-unpacking

I want to append a table with a list of function-returned values, some of them are tuples:

```
def get_foo_bar():
    # do stuff
    return 'foo', 'bar'

def get_apple():
    # do stuff
    return 'apple'

table = list()
table.append([get_foo_bar(), get_apple()])
```

This yields:

```
>>> table
[[('foo', 'bar'), 'apple']]
```

But i need the returned tuple to be unpacked into that list, like so:

```
[['foo', 'bar', 'apple']]
```

Since unpacking the function call `[*get_foo_bar()]` won't work, i assigned two variables for recieving the tuple's values and appended them instead:

```
foo, bar = get_foo_bar()
table.append([foo, bar, get_apple()])
```

This works, but can it be avoided?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`.extend()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
>>> table.extend(get_foo_bar())
>>> table.append(get_apple())
>>> [table]
[['foo', 'bar', 'apple']]
```

Or, you can concatenate tuples:

```
>>> table = []
>>> table.append(get_foo_bar() + (get_apple(),))
>>> table
[('foo', 'bar', 'apple')]
```